# Segmentation fault for structure pointer

Tags: c, segmentation-fault

I am new in C, and i wrote the following code

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>

typedef struct
{
    int name1;
}check1;
typedef struct
{
    int name2;
}check2;

int main()
{
    check1 *test1;
    check2 *test2;
    test1->name1=1;
    test2->name2=2;
    return 0;
}
```

When I am executing it, it is giving me an error:

```
$ gcc test1.c
$ ./a.out
Memory fault
```

In gdb:-

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x000000000040045e in main ()
```

What could be the reason???

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have declared two pointers, but you haven't allocated any memory for them to point to. The pointers are pointing to invalid memory.

Try this:

```
check1 *test1 = malloc(sizeof(*test1));
if (test1 == NULL)
    // report failure

check2 *test2 = malloc(sizeof(*test2));
if (test2 == NULL)
    // report failure
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also declare variables on the stack and assign their addresses to pointers.

```
check checka;
check* pcheck = &checka;
printf("%i",pcheck->name1);
```